# Is it OK to use Firebase RemoteConfig to store API Keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Note: For clarification this is not the Firebase API Key, this may be more like a token...something that the client app possesses, and the server endpoint verifies.

We are trying to do even better to secure an API Key (think token that is used to validate a client to an endpoint).   This will all be on our internal network, but we still want to be sure that only our mobile client can call the endpoint.

I was thinking that we could put the API Key in a Firebase remote config parameter (with an invalid default value built into the app).  However, the Firebase documentation for remote config says:

> Don't store confidential data in Remote Config parameter keys or parameter values. It is possible to decode any parameter keys or values stored in the Remote Config settings for your project.

I wasn't sure if this is just referring to the default values that are bundled with the app, or if it is also for values that are loaded remotely.  Once we have the key, we can encrypt it and store it on the device via our MDM provider.

Also, is the transfer of the remote config data to the app encrypted or done clear text?

Thanks for any more information that anyone can provide about the remote config.

Comment: In the context of Firebase an API key is usually not identifying a specific client, but it's a simple value that allows the connecting client to be tied to its back-end project. It's explicitly **not** a security leak to embed those in your app. It sounds like your API keys are different, but in that case you might want to consider using a different name for them. :-)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how secure you want to keep your API Key. What does the API key allow someone to do? If it's simply to identify your app to another service, for example the YouTube Data API, then the worst that can happen is that a malicious user uses up your quota for that resource. On the other hand, if the key allows the holder to make some irreversible changes to important data without further authentication and authorization, then you never want it stored on their device in any form.

Your quote from the Firebase documentation answers your question. In general, you should not be storing private keys in your app. Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778429/secure-keys-in-ios-app-scenario-is-it-safe) for thorough explanations.

Using Firebase's Remote Config is hardly more secure than shipping keys in the app bundle. Either way, the data ends up on users' hardware. A malicious person can then theoretically access it, no matter how difficult we may think that is to do.

Also, I can't say for sure (you should be able to easily test this) but I HIGHLY doubt that remote config values are sent as plain text. Google does everything over https by default.

Answer (score 3):

@Frank van Puffelen can confirm this, but from my understanding Firebase Remote Config uses **HTTPS** over **HTTP** requests which makes it harder to sniff information shared between the app and Firebase Remote Config vs. decompiling the APK and reading the strings generated if [using string constants generated by Gradle build configurations](https://michiganlabs.com/2014/09/23/string-constants-generated-gradle-build-configurations/). For instance, when one debugs an app with a Network Proxy sniffer such as *Charles Proxy* you can’t view the endpoint details unless the app is compiled in Debug mode due to HTTPs requests and newer security measures in the latest API versions.

See [What makes "https" sites more secure than "http"?](https://www.quora.com/What-makes-https-sites-more-secure-than-http).

> HTTP protocol doesn’t use data encryption when transferring it, so your personal information can be intercepted or even manipulated by third parties. To capture network information (passwords, credit card numbers, users IDs, etc.) hackers use a method called “sniffing”. If network packets aren’t encrypted the data within them can be read and stolen with a help of hacker application.
>
> Alternatively, HTTPS keeps any kind of data, including passwords, text messages, and credit card details, safe during transits between your computer and the servers. HTTPS keeps your data confidential by using the TSL protocol, frequently referred to as SSL, a secure certificate which offers three layers of protection, such as encryption, data integrity, and authentication.SSL certificates use what is known as asymmetric Public Key Cryptography, or a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) system. A PKI system uses two different keys to encrypt communications: a public key and a private key. Anything that is encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted by the corresponding private key and vice-versa.Also, HTTPS can protect you from such hacker attacks as man-in-the-middle attacks, DNS rebinding, and replay attacks.

## Further Security Measures

1. [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard) offers String encryption according to their landing page. I've sent them a message and am awaiting how much this would cost for an indie developer.
2. Using a [public/private API key exchange](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-hide-your-api-key-in-android-600583/#Public/private%20API%20key%20exchange) may be an additional layer of security. However, I need to research the implementation further to better understand this option.