# How to secure fabric_api key in react-native ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric, info.plist

I have stored fabric_api key in Info.plist file.But I don't want to include my key and secret in the info.plist file when the the app is live.

what is the best way to keep fabric/crashlytics key secure?

Answer (score 0):

I only know several ways:

1. Just put it in a constant variable, or if you want under your struct that handles all your keys. That's it.
2. UserDefaults.
3. Use libraries to obfuscate somehow your keys, such as https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys
4. Keychain.

The last one is discussed by Apple.

> Keeping a private key in a keychain is a great way to secure it. The key data is encrypted on disk and accessible only to your app or the apps you authorize.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave

Also some interesting discussions:

1. [In iOS, how can I store a secret "key" that will allow me to communicate with my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760216/in-ios-how-can-i-store-a-secret-key-that-will-allow-me-to-communicate-with-my)
2. [swift3 - How to protect secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422714/swift3-how-to-protect-secret-key/40423579#40423579)

I hope this helps.