# iOS API Key: Is there an actual safe way to secure your API key when making http requests?

Tags: ios, security, httprequest, keychain, api-key

Currently, I am getting an API key from the server after logging in and using it to make http requests. I currently store the API key in the iPhone app's database. However, I've heard that I should store it in a `keychain` from a colleague. So, I searched on Stackoverflow and seen questions regarding this. It seems this isn't really a secure way of storing API keys at all.

[Secure keys in iOS App scenario, is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778429/secure-keys-in-ios-app-scenario-is-it-safe/14865695#14865695)

[In iOS, how can I store a secret "key" that will allow me to communicate with my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760216/in-ios-how-can-i-store-a-secret-key-that-will-allow-me-to-communicate-with-my)

I don't know a way to stop hackers from reverse engineering to get the API key from the iOS app. A user on StackOverflow basically said it will only overcomplicate things for little to no benefits.

I need to find the post, but someone recommended to just make sure you're making a secure API request (SSL certificate) and you have a way to remove the API key if someone is hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by @jake you should use a token tied up only to the user instead of an Api Key for all users, but other enhancements can be done for further protect your App when doing the http requests.

The user token can be a signed JWT token and then you can enhance the security of the communication between your server and the App with Certificate Pinning in order to protect against Man in the Middle Attacks.

Other techniques like the use of OAUTH2 and hiding secrets can be used to enhance the security of your App and you can read more about it [here](https://www.approov.io/blog/category/series-api-keys.html).

Keep in mind that Certificate Pinning [can be bypassed](https://www.approov.io/blog/the-problem-with-pinning.html) by hooking frameworks such as [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/) that contain modules specific to bypass the pinning, but still another layer of security that you should not discard once it will increase the effort necessary to hack your App on the device and will protect your App against Man in the Middle Attacks.

For ultimately security between your App and the back-end you should use an App integrity attestation service, that will guarantee at run-time that your App was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by using an SDK integrated in you App and a service running in the cloud.

On successful attestation of the App integrity a JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the back-end of your App and the attestation service in the cloud are aware and on failure the JWT is signed with a fake secret that the App back-end does not know, allowing this way for the App back-end to only serve requests when it can verify the signature in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the cloud attestation service is not known by the App it is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

You can find such a service in [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html) that have SDKs for several platforms, including IOS. The integration will also need a small check in the App back-end code to verify the JWT token in order the back-end can protect itself against fraudulent use.

[JWT Token](https://jwt.io/)

> Token Based Authentication
>
> JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.

[Certificate Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)

> Pinning is the process of associating a host with their expected X509 certificate or public key. Once a certificate or public key is known or seen for a host, the certificate or public key is associated or 'pinned' to the host. If more than one certificate or public key is acceptable, then the program holds a pinset (taking from Jon Larimer and Kenny Root Google I/O talk). In this case, the advertised identity must match one of the elements in the pinset.

[OAUTH2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
> application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
> behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
> between the resource owner and the HTTP service, or by allowing the
> third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf.  This
> specification replaces and obsoletes the OAuth 1.0 protocol described
> in RFC 5849.

Disclaimer: I work at Approov.

Answer (score 0):

A more secure mechanism would be to return an authentication token on login. This authentication token should be unique to the user. If you have proper authorization and security mechanisms on the backend (to mitigate DDOS attacks, injection attacks, users accessing other user’s data, etc) then who cares if they get their authorization token from the keychain or wherever it is stored? Since the authentication token is tied to their account you could just invalidate the token so it stops working if the user is malicious. And you could even disable their account altogether if you have the right mechanisms in place on the backend.

Many of the security mechanisms can be automated on the backend. Platforms like AWS can easily be configured to automatically disable accounts that are doing certain malicious calls to your backend.

Comment: That's how the API key works in my situation. It is unique to each user and can be deleted.